# Xamarin app closes itself after some time

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, android-tv

Hi I've been developing android tv app for a while. It just show some photos and movies and automatically download new content from ftp server.

Now I am debugging it on android tv box device with Visual studio for Mac and I'm almost there but after some time, like few hours app closes it self with no dialog on device or any error on IDE. I need it to work all day on promo tv. If anyone here could come up with the reason of this behaviour, I would be great full if You share it with me.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Review the `logcat` output when the app closes to see if the OS is killing the process and for what reason.

Comment: As @SushiHangover states, you need to provide more info (like `logcat` output). But even without this information, one plausible reason could be memory leaks piling and the OS killing it because of OOM killer.